# How to read xml data without using parser(dom,sax)?

Tags: java, xml

I am new to xml. I have to read all the elements of xml file without using a parser. 
please help me.I can make use of string functions with regular expressions.but i am not familiar with them. so please help me to give me a code to read atleast 2 xml elements one is root and other one is child.

Comment: First of all, your sample is not xml.

Second, to read those elements, if you don't use an xml parser, you'll be writing one to read them. That means you're reinventing the wheel. And that isn't a good thing.

Is there a reason for not using an xml parser?

Comment: ya its my assignment to do so...

Comment: So your assignment is essentially to write an xml parser then?

Comment: not like that i've to get all elements as when i use parser. both outputs should be match. i can use of string functions with regular expressions. but i am not sure about those

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the standard `java.io` package, specifically `java.io.FileReader` and `java.io.BufferedReader`.

This will enable you to read the xml file and get the content as standard `java.lang.String`.

Once you have the String you can make use of regular expressions to filter out your xml type data.

**This is definitely not the most effective way of writing a xml parser, and doesn't closely cover all the parsing abilities that a standard xml parser will provide.**

Comment: No need to parser.but i should get same output as when i use parser. ok but i am not sure about string expressions and regular expressions. could you give any idea about use of regular expressions with strings

Comment: See @Tim Pietzcker in answers.

Comment: Unfortunately not. But whenever I "do" regular expressions, I make use of this handy tool: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: I just realised I did not answer this question at all. Thanks for the up-vote anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your XML is valid and well-formed, and that tags of the same name cannot be nested, you can use the following regex to match an entire tag, for example for a tag named `child`:

```
<\s*child(?:(?!<\s*/\s*child).)+<\s*/\s*child\s*>
```

Be aware that to use this in a Java string, you'll have to double all the backslashes; and you want to compile the regex using the `Pattern.DOTALL` option.

Explanation (optional whitespace tokens removed for clarity):

```
<child       # match opening tag
(?:          # then match...
 (?!</child) # as long as it's not at the start of the closing tag:
 .           # any character
)+           # as many times as possible
</child>     # then match the closing tag
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" ?>

<company>

<employee id="001" sex="M" age="19">Premshree Pillai</employee>



<turnover>

<year id="2000">100,000</year>


</turnover>

</company>

Comment: This regex, like all regexes used on XML, works only in the trivial case where the element being matched contains no descendant elements that would also be matched.  Applied to `<child><child></child></child>`, it will incorrectly match `<child><child></child>`.

Comment: @Robert Rossney: Which is why I wrote in the very first sentence that this only works if tags of the same name cannot be nested.